# Javascript - image has left border ? how to remove

Tags: javascript, html

On a website there is a black line on the left of a picture about 1 or 2 pixels long.  I can't get rid of it after checking the code (border etc).  I think its a javascript problem.  The picture doesn't have the black line on the home page but does have it on subsequent pages.  There is no margin etc.  How would I identify/fix the problem

image with no black border
http://www.darkrome.com/tours/rome-tours/colosseum-coliseum-ancient-rome-tour

image with black border on left hand side
http://darkrome.com/tours/vatican-tours/extended-vatican-museum-tour-with-bramante-staircase

Comment: actually it has a black border on the first page too

Comment: Please copy the relevant code here too, so that the question is still valid when the link dies (or make a screenshot if you can't identify the relevant code).

Comment: i didn't spot the border on the home page. i will give you the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this black border (actually it is not a border but a background) is produced by

```
#tourDetFluidOuter {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: url(/images/tour-detail-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

just remove the background or cover it fully.

Comment: could i cover it ? i dont want to remove it

Comment: <div id="tourDetFluidOuter" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" style="display: block;">
Yep simon is right, it is a background for the above html element

Comment: make the size of the background smaller or cover it with another div whose background completely covers this one!

Comment: @Aindriu yes, you need to either stretch your image over it or make a fake container over it with `background: white;` or so

Comment: the black line is still there even if I remove background:

Comment: @Aindriu this is not true, I've just removed it in developer console and it disappeared

Comment: i tried unclicking it on the developer tools but it only removed the background image to white.

Comment: probably you remove it from the wrong element... are you sure you remove it from here `<div id="tourDetFluidOuter" itemscope="" itemtype="schema.org/Product"; style="display: block;">`?

Comment: i got it it disabled! - i didn't select the right div. i just have to remove it from the .css now. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Check out your css <s>and remove the background image</s>.

Actually the float: left is causing the issue, so you can remove it afaik

```
#tourDetFluidOuter {    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: url(/images/tour-detail-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem with the float is that once removed it leaves a white space instead of a black space.  I needed to move the container over to the left and be flush with white above